# Background Process in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am new to AWS and have a question about an application I'm trying to write. I have a bunch of data that sits within Amazon RDS. On a periodic basis, I would like a small snippet of code to run against this data and in certain situations have notifications sent where appropriate. Of all the AWS services, what is the best architecture for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a simple `cron` job running on an EC2 instance. The `cron` job could run a script (PHP, Perl, whatever) to go fetch the data and then do something with it (notify people, generate reports etc)

Does that help?

See here for details on getting started with a Linux instance: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/EC2_GetStarted.html

You could achieve the same results using a Windows machine and Scheduled Tasks. Here's the getting started guide for Windows instances: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/EC2Win_GetStarted.html

Comment: "notify people" : Using [**AWS SES**](http://aws.amazon.com/ses/) service most likely (unless the recipients are willing to rummage around in their spam folders)

Comment: Yes, I was assuming OP has already figured out the actual method of "notifying people". Any idea when SES will be out of Beta? Looks like a great product

Comment: @wwarren No idea.. but they can't take it away! They'll have to pry it from my cold/dead hands!

Comment: It's _that_ good, eh? Might have to look into this for another project I'm on... Thanks for that!

Comment: my question regarding this is can i run automation in the background and at the same time do something else like writing emails?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Scheduled Lambda service driven by CloudWatch events. It acts as a resilient cron.